@font-face ignored for local font
So I'm trying to create alias for some fonts and aliases are just ignored without any obvious reason. Check out this example. So I just created alias with name "Test" for "PingFang SC". And now I supposed that both Test/PingFang SC should effectively use same font. But no, just comment "font-family: PingFang SC" line and you will see that font will change. Any ideas why @font-face ignored?


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Test";
            src: local(PingFang SC);
        }

        .with-font {
            font-family: "Test";
            font-family: PingFang SC;
        }

    </style>
    <title>Font test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="with-font">对方出招有快有慢</div>
</body>
</html>




Are you absolutely certain that that is the correct local name of the font? I ask because I've just done an experiment (Edge/Window10) using Courier. It was not picked up by the src but was by the font-family. Looking at Word to check I see that it is actually called Courier New, and that worked as the src.

So yes, seems like I have to provide not font family in local source.
Seems like this works:
src: local(PingFangSC-Regular)

This works:
src: local(PingFangSC-Regular)
But it means to create alias for some existing font I will have to provide @font-face for each weight.

It also means your text will only be rendered in "PingFangSC-Regular" for users who have installed this font locally
